# bash auto complete binary file which is not in PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a custom bash auto completion script on my CLI package.

When I install my package like below, then my command is installed in $PATH (/usr/local/bin),

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

so `complete -o filenames -F _mycommand mycommand` in my `bash-autocomplete.sh` works properly.
(Because command `mycommand` is in $PATH (/usr/local/bin)

However, when I install my package locally, and then try to execute binary file from installed location like below,

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr
$ make
$ make install
```

`complete -o filenames -F _mycommand mycommand` doesn't work because OS don't know the location of `mycommand`.

```
$ ~/uftrace$ $HOME/usr/bin/mycommand [TAB]
Command 'command' not found,
```

My question is this:

How can I make bash completion feature with my local binary file? (which is not in PATH)
Can I do this by fixing `Makefile` or `configure` or `bash-autocomplete.sh`?

+

Install the package locally, and than add PATH is not an option because I want to make this bash auto-completion feature regardless of installation location. I want to this feature work at installation point.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. In particular, what's in `_mycommand`?

Comment: @KangMinchul : How could `complete` possibly know, which directory you have installed the command to? Today, you put it into ~/bin, and tomorrow maybe into ~/local or somewhere else.

Comment: `complete -o filenames -F _mycommand "$HOME"/usr/bin/mycommand`?

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html), that's not possible unless using an "intelligent" completion loader:

> First, the command name is identified. [...]
> If the command word is a full pathname, a compspec for the full pathname is
> searched for first. **If no compspec is found for the full pathname, an
> attempt is made to find a compspec for the portion following the final
> slash**.

I put an emphasis (or bold) on the part that should apply: bash will be able to complete the full path (eg: `/usr/mycommand` or even `./mycommand`) but it won't be able to resolve `mycommand` unless it is found in the `PATH` and where some completion does the trick.

At last resort, you could register a completion loader which may for example look at the command (using `${1##*/}` to get the basename):

```
_completion_loader() {
  if [[ "${1}" == mycommand || "${1##*/}" == mycommand ]]; then
    complete -o filenames -F _mycommand "$1"
    return 124
  fi
  return 1 # 
}
complete -D -F _completion_loader -o bashdefault -o default
```

I would not do that on Linux, due to chance of bash-completion begin already there and providing completion by itself: you could check [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) as they may perhaps have a way to handle your completion, for example by saving in `/etc/bash_completion.d/<yourcommand>.bash`.